# How to use values from that is obtained from a function call within a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to use values from a function call (`Bmi` in `BMI`) within another function (`HealthCat`) and I'm trying to use the values obtained to perform control flow to get desired output onto my html. However, I am not sure how can I utilize the values from the double function call. Help is greatly appreciated! thx in advance!

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <title>BMI Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>BMI Calculator</h1>
    <p>
      <label>Enter weight:</label>
      <input type="text" id="weight" placeholder = "Enter your weight in kg">
    </p>

    <p>
      <label>Enter height:</label>
      <input type="text" id="height" placeholder="Enter your height in m">
    </p>

    <!--Display-->
    <input type="button" onclick="BMI()" value="BMI"/>
    <p id="result"></p>

    <input type="button" onclick="HealthCat()" value="HealthCat"/>
    <p id="Hresult"></p>

    <script src="bmiScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my javascript:

```
function BMI(){
   var Weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
   var Height = document.getElementById("height").value;
   var Bmi = Weight/(Height*Height);
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = Bmi;
}

function HealthCat(){
   BMI();
   if(Bmi<18.50){
      document.getElementById("Hresult").innerHTML="Under weight";

   }else if (Bmi>18.5 && Bmi <23) {
      document.getElementById("Hresult").innerHTML="Normal weight";

   }else if (Bmi>23 && Bmi <27.5) {
      document.getElementById("Hresult").innerHTML="Over weight";

   }else if (Bmi>27.5) {
      document.getElementById("Hresult").innerHTML="Obese";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the value of a local variable in one function from another function. Once the execution of a function completes, the local variables are `destroyed` and can no longer be used. To use the `Bmi` variable from outside the `BMI` function, you need to return the variable so that the calling function can use it:

```
function BMI(){
   var Weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
   var Height = document.getElementById("height").value;
   var Bmi =  Weight/(Height*Height);
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =Bmi;
   return Bmi; // Return the Bmi value.
}

function HealthCat(){
   var Bmi = BMI(); // Use the returned Bmi value
   if(Bmi<18.50){
      document.getElementById("Hresult").innerHTML="Under weight";

   }else if (Bmi>18.5 && Bmi <23) {
      document.getElementById("Hresult").innerHTML="Normal weight";

   }else if (Bmi>23 && Bmi <27.5) {
      document.getElementById("Hresult").innerHTML="Over weight";

   }else if (Bmi>27.5) {
      document.getElementById("Hresult").innerHTML="Obese";
   }
}
```

Comment: For the shake of completeness, you could declare Bmi as a global variable, but the approach in this answer is way better (it doesn't pollute the global space).

Comment: Thx man! It didn't occur to me I can use return as I am new to javascript.